# Combining matrix in data frame through aggregate

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, xtable

I'm trying to compute quantiles by factor and print out the resulting aggregate to latex format using xtable. Unfortunately, I'm getting some wonky behavior. And a clean solution would be appreciated.

To create an example:

```
tm <- data.frame(f=c("a","b","c"),v=runif(30))
tm$f <- factor(tm$f)
agv <- aggregate(v~f,tm, quantile)
```

The output `agv` isn't accepted by xtable:

```
xtable(agv)
```

gives

> Error in cols[, i + pos] <- do.call("formatC", curFormatArgs) :
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

even though `print(agv)` is

```
  f        v.0%       v.25%       v.50%       v.75%      v.100%
1 1 0.002970944 0.253247687 0.571891610 0.766606825 0.986142807
2 2 0.002129951 0.328739086 0.558132094 0.799115979 0.991067470
3 3 0.011059184 0.285322522 0.496035672 0.770908599 0.994420787
```

because apparently `dim(agv)` is actually `[1] 3 2`

So I tried:

```
cbind(featureName=agv$f, agv$v)
```

which results in the character factors converting to numeric values for some reason.

After some trial and error, this is the solution I settled on:

```
cbind(f=as.character(agv$f), data.frame(agv$v,check.names=F))
```

which, gives me the result I want in `xtable`:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrr}
  \hline
 & f & 0\% & 25\% & 50\% & 75\% & 100\% \\
  \hline
1 & a & 0.00 & 0.25 & 0.48 & 0.75 & 0.99 \\
  2 & b & 0.00 & 0.28 & 0.46 & 0.74 & 1.00 \\
  3 & c & 0.02 & 0.21 & 0.44 & 0.63 & 1.00 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Anyway, I'm just curious whether there's a cleaner solution with fewer lines involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly more direct approach (though not much different conceptually than what you've already done) might be to use `do.call(data.frame, ...)`. The following works for me.

```
xtable(do.call(data.frame, c(agv, check.names = FALSE)))
```

For me, that returns:

```
> xtable(do.call(data.frame, c(agv, check.names = FALSE)))
% latex table generated in R 3.0.0 by xtable 1.7-1 package
% Thu Apr 25 11:10:26 2013
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrr}
  \hline
 & f & v.0\% & v.25\% & v.50\% & v.75\% & v.100\% \\ 
  \hline
1 & a & 0.06 & 0.27 & 0.38 & 0.64 & 0.94 \\ 
  2 & b & 0.20 & 0.38 & 0.52 & 0.70 & 0.87 \\ 
  3 & c & 0.01 & 0.22 & 0.60 & 0.87 & 0.99 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

---

`xtable` also works with `data.table`s, so you can also do something like the following:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(tm, key = "f")
xtable(DT[, as.list(quantile(v)), by = key(DT)])
```

Here, `DT[, as.list(quantile(v)), by = key(DT)]` will give you the same results as your "agv" object.